# Member's Title and Description

Tags: php, html, css

I have made an advertising website that allows people to sign up and display the details and descriptions of their job. My question is, do I have to make a page for each member’s description separately? 
I ask because if I receive thousands of members then it will be too time-consuming and difficult to make each page separately.

Comment: why?? no need to create separate page for every member

Comment: Do the Full USE of PHP and MySQL.

Comment: O.o - Not sure if trolling or not using a database...

Comment: Of course not. You should have their data stored in a database, and only **one** page that displays user data this way: 1) receive user identification in input (e.g. username) 2) fetch user data from database with the ID 3) display user data

Comment: This question shows that you may not have a great grasp of web development. I'd suggest hiring an experienced web developer who could do this for you.

Comment: I'm a beginner web developer. Thank you so much for the speedy reply.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look on PHP and MySQL.
You can create dynamic pages with PHP and store info in MySQL.

PHP is a serverside language, and will run on the server, thus the sourcecode won't be sent to the client.

Comment: I'm a beginner web developer. Thank you so much for the speedy reply.